# Looking up an object property within the console. Syntax issue

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, console.log

I'm writing a compare function using objects. I know that if I have the following object - var obj{ one: "foo", two: bar"} and I want to look up a property then obj["one"] will work but obj[one] will not.

However when I do the comparison function it will correctly compare obj["one"] and obj2["one"], but when I'm trying to log it in the console the syntax obj[one] works and obj["one"] comes back as undefined. It doesn't affect the functionality of the code, but I'm confused.

```
var num = 2;
var num2 = 4;
var num3 = 4;
var num4 = 9;
var num5 = "4";
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
var obj2 = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};

function deepEqual(el, el2) {
  var outcome = false;
  console.log("comparing " + el + " and " + el2);
  if (typeof el == 'object' && typeof el2 == 'object') {
    console.log("These are both objects");
    if (Object.keys(el).length === Object.keys(el2).length) {
      console.log("These objects have the same number of keys");
      for (var x in el) {
        if (el2.hasOwnProperty(x) && el["x"] === el2["x"]) {
          console.log("comparing " + el[x] + " with " + el2[x]);
          outcome = true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

      }
    } else return false;
  } else if (el === el2) {
    outcome = true;
  }

  return outcome;
}
```

So the part of the code I'm talking about is

```
if (el2.hasOwnProperty(x) && el["x"] === el2["x"]) {
  console.log("comparing " + el[x] + " with " + el2[x]);
  outcome = true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

This comes back correctly in the console as "comparing (property) with (property)". However if I write it like this

```
if (el2.hasOwnProperty(x) && el["x"] === el2["x"]) {
  console.log("comparing " + el["x"] + " with " + el2["x"]);
  outcome = true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

It says "comparing undefined with undefined".
Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code el["x"] does not refer to anything. There is no property in the el object that has an "x" key

you are in a for loop which define x so you need to use that variable instead of "x"

```
for (var x in el) {

            if (el2.hasOwnProperty(x) && el[x] === el2[x]) {
                console.log("comparing " + el[x] + " with " + el2[x]);
                outcome = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

}
```

Comment: You're right. I don't know why but before it was working with the quotes in the if statement but not with the quotes in the console.log within the if statement. When I took the quotes out of the if statement, the compare didn't work correctly...although it seems to be working fine now. I'm not sure why it would work with the quotes in the if statement if that was the issue. Thanks though.

Comment: don't know if it can help understand but el["x"] === el2["x"] will be true if both are undefined